# Python 3.4 Pandas DataFrame Structuring

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.4

## QUESTION

How can I get rid of the repeated column labels for each line of data?

## CODE

```
req = urllib.request.Request(newIsUrl)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
dRespData = respData.decode('utf-8')

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Ticker', 'GW', 'RE', 'OE', 'NI', 'CE'])

    df = df.append({'Ticker':ticker,
                        'GW':gw,
                         'RE':rt,
                         'OE':oe,
                         'NI':netInc,
                         'CE':capExp}, ignore_index= True)
    print(df)

yhooKeyStats()



acquireData()
```

## OUTCOME

```
Ticker      GW           RE             OE            NI            CE    

0 MMM   [7,050,000]  [34,317,000]   [13,109,000]  [4,956,000]  [(1,493,000)]

Ticker      GW           RE             OE            NI            CE    

0 ABT   [17,501,000]  [7,412,000]   [12,156,000]  [2,437,000]
```

## NOTES

- all of the headers and data line up respectively
- headers are repeated in the dataframe for each line of data

Comment: The code indentations aren't exactly right because the stackoverflow GUI demanded it to be reformatted

Comment: I fixed your formatting, but you're missing a value.

Comment: format code by highlighting and ctrl+k (or use the {} button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip every other line with a slice and iloc:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['A', 1, 'A', 3], 1: ['B', 2, 'B', 4]})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   0  1
0  A  B
1  1  2
2  A  B
3  3  4

In [13]: df.iloc[1::2]
Out[13]:
   0  1
1  1  2
3  3  4
```